# Wait a page code running until another page triggers it

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Edit:** To make my point, I need some back story.

I was shopping online today and entered my credit card number as well as tons of other info to the e-commerce site. Then e-commerce site redirected me to my bank's page which asks an confirmation code sent to my mobile phone. I entered the code and the bank redirected me to e-commerce paid failed page.

I needed to enter all the information I gave to e-commerce site again because hitting back won't help for security reasons. So I started to think, how would I write that e-commerce site payment page, so that it opens a new tab for my bank's page asking confirmation code and won't go any further until my bank confirms payment. I don't think this is as easy as parsing response because bank does not respond directly to first request. Think this like "login using Facebook account" button. You need like 10 steps and a token to do that. (which I cannot understand how it works, since I am a newbee)

I hope I am clear now.

**Original post:**

I am new at this, please bear with me. I googled to find a solution but got more confused.

I am writing a login system like this for learning:

> user form (`login.aspx`) -> posts to 3rd party server -> 3rd party server asks more credentials -> 3rd party server calls `logedin.aspx` (if successful) or `failedlogin.aspx` (if fails)

That is easy to implement. I wonder if I can do something like this:

1. on user form (`login.aspx`), user clicks on submit button
2. onclick event posts to 3rd party server and waits for it to request either `logedin.aspx` or `failedlogin.aspx`
3. resume running and display authentication result on `login.aspx`

So user won't see `logedin.aspx` or `failedlogin.aspx`

I think I need an object in `login.aspx` to wait, until it is released in `logedin.aspx` or `failedlogin.aspx` or a timeout is hit.

How to wait in a page and resume from a trigger on another page? Please point some direction for me to look at.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're calling a website from server-side code, you'd likely end up using something like `HttpClient` or `HttpWebRequest` or some other .NET object used to send requests to and receive requests from websites.  The code would craft the request, send it, wait for the response, and then you can do whatever you like with the response.  It doesn't matter if this happens in ASP.NET or in any other .NET application.

Comment: @David, thank you. I do `HttpWebRequest ` but cannot use response because 3rd party server posts data some other page.

Comment: How do you know what the 3rd party server does?  The only information provided by a server is what's in the response.  If that data doesn't contain what you need then you simply don't have the data that you need.

Comment: @David, I am sorry being not clear. While I am posting data to 3rd party server, I post an URL to succeed and an URL to fail, both on my server. 3rd party server redirects to one of them. I just wonder if I can prevent redirection and stay on my login screen.

Comment: A redirect is itself a response.  You should be able to examine the response from the `HttpWebRequest` and see which URL it's redirecting to.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an HTTP request to the 3rd party server with something like the `HttpWebRequest` object (or `HttpClient`).  The response from that request would have the information you're looking for.

Based on the comments above, it sounds like the response is an [HTTP redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302).  In that case the header(s) in the response would have the information you need.  For example, if the headers contain this:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.yourdomain.com/logedin.aspx
```

Then the request resulted in a redirect to `logedin.aspx`.  Based on that information you can perform your server-side logic and respond back to your user as you need.

Comment: @Ertug: This is sounding more and more like you're trying to short-circuit an OAuth-like flow of information.  That won't work.  By design.  The entire purpose of a setup like that is so the user's sensitive information is only ever exchanged between the user and the trusted third party provider.  That user's sensitive information should *never* be intercepted by an intermediary source, such as your website.  An entire industry exists to prevent you from doing exactly this.  Please don't try to collect banking data from your users.

Comment: I am not on a project or something. Just curious. I entered all the information e-commerce site needed. E-commerce site is redirecting to bank site and bank site redirects to e-commerce site, but some other page of them. If payment is done this works but if fails, the process should be done all over again. I was trying to find a way for user not to re-enter all the information again. It is for good use.

Comment: @Ertug: The bottom line is that the only information your server has is information that's either provided by the user or provided by the 3rd party when making server-side HTTP requests to that 3rd party.  If you want the user to provide you with their information, present a form asking them to do that.  Take that information, send it to the 3rd party website, and handle the response.  There's a *very good chance* that the 3rd party website isn't going to like this approach, because they won't want you compromising the security of *their* users' sensitive information.

Comment: David, thank you. I appreciate. Though I totally failed to make my point.